# Multiple Line Graph by using SQL query (Yearly Comparison Graph)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, graph, highcharts

I am trying to generate a multiple line graph with Highcharts, where each line represents data from a different year, and the x-axis displays the date while the y-axis displays the price.

I have a MySQL database table from which I'm fetching data, and I'm grouping that data by year using PHP. The `$chart_data` array holds the data grouped by year, and the `name` key holds the year value while the `data` key holds an array of timestamp and price pairs.

I've included the PHP code I'm using to generate the chart, and it successfully generates the graph, but the data is not displaying correctly. The graph shows all the years on the same line instead of each year on its own line.

I'm expecting the graph to look like the one in this reference image Demo Graph Screenshot, with each year displayed on its own line.

I'm new to Highcharts and not sure how to adjust the code to display the graph correctly. Can anyone help me with this issue? Thank you in advance!

Here is the code I'm using to generate the chart:

### // SQL Query...

```
<?php
$chart_record = $wpdb->get_results($SQL_ALL_TBL_FOR_CHART);

$chart_title = '';
if ($chart_record){
    $row = $chart_record[0];
    $chart_title = $row->var_name . ' | ' . $row->type_name;
    $chart_data = array();

    $grouped_data = array();
    foreach ($chart_record as $row) {
        $year = $row->year;
        if (!isset($grouped_data[$year])) {
            $grouped_data[$year] = array();
        }

        $date = new DateTime($row->rptl_date);
        $timestamp = $date->getTimestamp() * 1000;

        $grouped_data[$year][] = array(
            'x' => $timestamp,
            'y' => (int) $row->rptl_price
        );
    }

    foreach ($grouped_data as $year => $year_data) {
        $chart_data[] = array(
            'name' => $year,
            'data' => $year_data
        );
    }
}
?>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div id="chart-container"></div>
</div>

<script>
Highcharts.chart('chart-container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: '<?php echo $chart_title; ?>'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        title: {
            text: 'Date'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Price'
        }
    },
    series: [
        <?php foreach ($chart_data as $year_data): ?> {
            name: '<?php echo $year_data["name"]; ?>',
            data: [
                <?php foreach ($year_data["data"] as $data): ?>[<?php echo $data["x"]*1000; ?>,
                    <?php echo $data["y"]; ?>],
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            ]
        },
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    ]
});
</script>
```

The output of this code is:

[image: Chart Screenshot which I made by SQL query]

I was expecting this code to generate the graph as I have provided the reference image [image: Demo Graph Screenshot]
But the issue is clear to you. Please help me with this problem. Thank you!

[Chart Grouped data ooutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xywn9.png)

Answer (score 0):

As per the code, it seems that the issue might be with the data. Each year data should be in a separate series, but currently, all the data is being added to a single series.

Please check the below code. It might help you.

```html
// SQL Query...
get_results($SQL_ALL_TBL_FOR_CHART);

$chart_title = '';
if ($chart_record){
    $row = $chart_record[0];
    $chart_title = $row->var_name . ' | ' . $row->type_name;
    $chart_data = array();
    $grouped_data = array();
    foreach ($chart_record as $row) {
        $year = $row->year;
        if (!isset($grouped_data[$year])) {
            $grouped_data[$year] = array(
                'name' => $year,
                'data' => array()
            );
        }
        $date = new DateTime($row->rptl_date);
        $timestamp = $date->getTimestamp() * 1000;
        $grouped_data[$year]['data'][] = array(
            'x' => $timestamp,
            'y' => (int) $row->rptl_price
        );
    }
    foreach ($grouped_data as $year => $year_data) {
        $chart_data[] = $year_data;
    }
}
?>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div id="chart-container"></div>
</div>

<script>
    Highcharts.chart('chart-container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: '<?php echo $chart_title; ?>'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            title: {
                text: 'Date'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Price'
            }
        },
        series: <?php echo json_encode($chart_data); ?>
    });
</script>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I've added the updated code provided by you but it is not working as per my concern.
This code does not change anything on the frontend(graph/chart). Moreover, I've tried this `series: <?php echo json_encode($chart_data); ?>` earlier but it is not working in my side.

Comment: Could you pass the SQL query response?

Comment: SQL Response:
First 3 arrays:
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [year] => 2024 [org_id] => 1 [cat_id] => 4 [type_id] => 2 [var_id] => 1 [var_name] => 1121 [rptl_price] => 810 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [year] => 2024 [org_id] => 1 [cat_id] => 4 [type_id] => 2 [var_id] => 1 [var_name] => 1121 [rptl_price] => 825 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [year] => 2024 [org_id] => 1 [cat_id] => 4 [type_id] => 2 [var_id] => 1 [var_name] => 1121 [rptl_price] => 815 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [year] => 2023 [org_id] => 1 [cat_id] => 4 [type_id] => 2 [var_id] => 1 [var_name] => 1121 [rptl_price] => 800 )

Comment: Next three arrays:
[4] => stdClass Object ( [year] => 2023 [org_id] => 1 [cat_id] => 4 [type_id] => 2 [var_id] => 1 [var_name] => 1121 [rptl_price] => 782 ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [year] => 2023 [org_id] => 1 [cat_id] => 4 [type_id] => 2 [var_id] => 1 [var_name] => 1121 [rptl_price] => 800 ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [year] => 2020 [org_id] => 1 [cat_id] => 4 [type_id] => 2 [var_id] => 1 [var_name] => 1121 [rptl_price] => 770 ) )

Sorry, i could not put all of it in 1 comment, because of character limit

Comment: I've added the output of the `$chart_data` as a screenshot in my question. The code is working fine till grouping the data. I think the issue is with the output displaying on the graph(chart).

Comment: Please check the hightchart series format and then format  accordingly and pass into series variable.

Comment: I've identified the issue:
Issue was with the timestamp (it was the same on every record)
That's why the code is not showing the expected graph.